# final variable issue in an inner class

Tags: android, null

Could you please tell me what is the error here? it tells me that "gender" in toast make must be set to final but when I do, the if statements complain that it should not be final

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String gender = null;

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ok, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.createprofile);



    RadioButton rb_male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradiobutton);
String   male=rb_male.getText().toString();

    RadioButton rb_female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradiobutton);
    String female=rb_male.getText().toString();

    if(rb_male.isChecked()) { gender = "male";}
    if(rb_female.isChecked()){ gender = "female";}

    Button checkgender = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gendercheck);
    checkgender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, gender.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });




}




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many errors in there to really address completely.  They include:

1. You grab text from the button into variables, then you write out literal strings "male" and "female" anyway.
2. You were grabbing text from the male button twice, and never the female button.
3. Declare your variables in the class, not in the onCreate method, and they will behave much better with no problems about being final and so on.
4. Your `if` statements checking the male and female buttons must be inside the method onClick(v).  If they are outside, then a click does not cause them to be reevaluated and no amount of changing your buttons will change the result you get.
5. `gender` is already a String, `gender.toString()` does nothing to change that.
6. RadioButton don't really do what you want, you probably want ToggleButton.
7. You probably want to put some logic in so only one of the buttons male or female can be checked at a time.  They would each need a OnClickListener to do this.

Having said all that, here is the code with a lot of those changes made and probably some other stuff cleaned up a bit.

Good luck!

public class AndroidTest extends Activity {

```
   String gender = null;
   RadioButton rb_male;
   RadioButton rb_female;
   Button checkgender;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       rb_male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradiobutton);
       rb_female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradiobutton);

       checkgender = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gendercheck);
       checkgender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (rb_male.isChecked()) {
                   gender = "male";
               }
               if (rb_female.isChecked()) {
                   gender = "female";
               }
               Toast.makeText(AndroidTest.this, (CharSequence) gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
   }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You can't access a local non final variable from an inner class. One easy workaround is to take another final variable after setting the initial value for gender. Do like this:

```
if(rb_male.isChecked()) { gender = "male";}
if(rb_female.isChecked()){ gender = "female";}
final String finalGender = gender;
```

and later

```
Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, finalGender.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

There are also other ways of doing it but this is the fastest.

Comment: small correction, non-final local variable (which are defined inside method). non-final instance variable can be accessed.

Comment: Thank you, it runs, but then the toast keeps giving me " male " all the time !

Comment: Can you correect it please, because i still cant see the error

Comment: The code I provided is correct. If you always get "male" it means rb_male.isChecked() always returns true. To make sure of this just log the value after being set with Log.d("CheckGender", "Gender is " + gender); The message will be printed in LogCat console.

Comment: I do the log with gender or with final gender ( when i do it with gender it gives me the final error)?

Comment: with the FinalGender it gives me male still in the logcat.

Comment: I forgot to mention, log the information right after if(rb_female.isChecked()){ gender = "female";}. Here you just set in gender variable the value you want to display. If the value is not  what you expect it means the error is in the code setting the gender variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

```
Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, gender.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

should be

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), gender.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And you can also make gender a class scope variable so that you can access it with a setter/getter

Comment: It still gives me the same error, basically what you have done is to add .show() but my problem is not GUI related.. it is about the definiton of the variable gender

Answer (score 1):

your are missing .show() in onclick toast:

```
      public void onClick(View v) {

                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, gender.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: It still gives me the same error, basically what you have done is to add .show() but my problem is not GUI related.. it is about the definiton of the variable gender