# Android SDK. Access old variable in new Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-2.2-froyo, runnable

I have been able to call an http post process in a new thread, but the variables sent over the post vary based off of the value of another variable, posttype, set before this thread is run.

The variable that determines what values are sent over the post is set as: `public String posttype = "load";`

before the new thread is run posttype is set as either "load" or "unload". Based off of these values, the data sent over post is determined.

the new thread function I use is from: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

I use the SECOND function shown of runnable from the above link.

Inside the first `run()` I sent the variables over http. Inside the second `run()` I parse the returned variable.

The problem is this: I cannot access the value of the posttype and the `else` statement inside the new thread function is always chosen because the `if` statement cannot access the variable posttype.

How to I make the variable `posttype` truly global or usable by a new thread?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't try to communicate with threads through global variables like this.  The best thing that can happen is that it obviously fails every time.  The worst is that is seems to work and you deliver it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right you can't access the variable because it's not final. If so you can take a final variable of the same type as posttype, assign it that value and use it in the second run. 
To make it more clear check my answer to this question: [final variable issue in an inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236446/final-variable-issue-in-an-inner-class/10236531#comment13154901_10236531)

The listener in that case is run in a situation where the same logic applies.

Comment: Could it have been simpler! Thanks. For others, the ONLY change I made was adding a `final String posttype2 = posttype;` INSIDE the `run()` statement for the new thread. The new thread's `if` statement was able to properly read posttype2 (indirectly posttype), because posttype2 is set to posttype every time the thread is run.